# Cross-referencing appendices in RevTex4.2

Tags: equations, numbering, appendices, revtex

I am seeing everywhere that appendices should be numbered (or rather "lettered") automatically, and one should be able to reference them using simple `label{}` and `\ref{}`, which does not work for me:

```
\documentclass[aps,prl,reprint]{revtex4-2}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\title{Whatever}
\author{Myself}
\affiliation{Here}
\date{\today}

\begin{abstract}
Abstract...
\end{abstract}

\maketitle

\section{Body}
As shown in Appendix \ref{app}:
\begin{align}
    2+2=4
\end{align}

\onecolumngrid
\appendix

\section{Proof}
\label{app}
Notice that:
\begin{align}
    1+1=2
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Also, all the equations appear numbered normally, and I would like equations in the appendices to be numbered with the letter of the appendix, i.e. (A1) for the first equation in the first appendix, etc.

Comment: @campa, but according to the Physical Review Style and Notation Guide (https://journals.aps.org/prl/authors), the equations in the appendix should be numered as (A.1), etc.

Comment: Uhm, something is very strange. As far as I can see with `prl` nothing is numbered at all, so there is nothing "wrong"; and it wouldn't be the first time that the class and the guidelines do not really match. However, I don't really understand where this is coming from...

Comment: Yes, there is no numbering of sections, but I don't need that. On the other hand I am seeing some PRL papers and they usually have appendices in a separate file (suplementary material), so maybe I don't need to number/cross-reference at all.